# what is the proublem ? ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio-2.1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
  >   Failed to transform artifact 'x86_debug.jar (io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
  >   Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\USER.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\x86_debug\1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695\b6634f91d3c77e2c3ec9b53abd9c0203a18a3d25\x86_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.jar.
  >   Failed to transform 'C:\Users\USER.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\x86_debug\1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695\b6634f91d3c77e2c3ec9b53abd9c0203a18a3d25\x86_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: invalid entry size (expected 27689296 but got 27687917 bytes). (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
  >   Failed to transform artifact 'x86_64_debug.jar (io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
  >   Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\USER.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\x86_64_debug\1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695\40b4f81a66d09624710dd7fff2bd600092231ead\x86_64_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.jar.
  >   Failed to transform 'C:\Users\USER.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\x86_64_debug\1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695\40b4f81a66d09624710dd7fff2bd600092231ead\x86_64_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: invalid entry size (expected 28517464 but got 28517372 bytes). (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
- Try:
  Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output. Run with `--scan` to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Did you try flutter clean command in terminal? and run project using flutter run command

Answer (score 1):

I got similar problem. After upgrading all packages, my problem resolved.